# Calculating the divergence of a central vector field.

Tags: vector-spaces, vector-analysis, vector-fields

I am trying to calculate the divergence of a central electric field, namely the electric field due to a point charge and my book begins like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLeOr.jpg

However in the last line I am unsure of how they get that $r\frac{df}{dr}$, I have been staring at the book for ages and cant seem to figure it out.

Thanks.

Comment: Product rule of differentiation.

Comment: Could you show a little more please

Comment: Tried to work through the details, but discovered that I don't get it either. Sorry.

Comment: You're more likely to get an answer if you type the full question here. Some people don't like embedded images, and lots of people don't like linked images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From vector calculus$$\nabla \cdot (f(r) \,\mathbf r)=f(r)\,(\nabla \cdot \mathbf r)+\nabla f(r) \cdot \mathbf r=$$$$3f(r)+\frac {f'(r)}r\,\mathbf r \cdot \mathbf r$$(see one of the properties in [divergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence))

Note that the second $\nabla$ in the sum is the *gradient* of $f$.

Now $$r=\sqrt {x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2}$$ so, by the chain rule $$\frac {\partial r}{\partial x_i}=\frac {x_i}{r}$$ hence, yet by the chain rule$$\frac {\partial f}{\partial x_i}=f'(r)\frac {\partial r}{\partial x_i}=\frac {f'(r)}r x_i$$ Done !